# Key board hides textField when Orientation Changes?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation, orientation-changes

I have two textfields in a subview as viewLogin. when try to enter text key board is hiding them. I solved that problem by moving the viewLogin.
Code is...

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/9, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
    else {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2.5, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
    else {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Problem here i facing is if i first change the orientation to Landscape and click on textField its working fine but if i first click on textField in portrait mode and then changed to Landscape left/right its not working..

can some help me to solve this....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Apple uses (take a look at the [KeyboardAccessory example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009462)): First, register for keyboard notifications in `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and make sure you unregister in `viewDidUnload`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

then add these methods to your implementation:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSValue *keyboardEndFrameValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect keyboardRect = [keyboardEndFrameValue CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
    CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
    newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop - self.view.bounds.origin.y;

    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                     animations:^{
                         self.textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
                     }];
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                     animations:^{
                         self.textView.frame = self.view.bounds;
                     }];
}
```

I'm using it and I do not have any problems with orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

because your textFieldDidBeginEditing method are called later in first case and in second case it before called so you have to code in your shouldChangeCharactersInRange of textfield editing

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation ==  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2.5, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
}
else {
    viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to resolve this... Dont Get into UIDeviceOrientation.. use

UIInterfaceOrientation

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/9, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
    else {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2.5, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
    else {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
}
     -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
        {

            if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

                viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/9, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
            }
            else {
                viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
            }
            return YES;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register to the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, and move this code to the method that gets invoked when the notification is thrown. So, if you first click on textField in portrait mode and then changed to Landscape, this method is invoked first.
Dont forget to check the orientation before you change the frame.(ie, do it only if the orientation is landscape)

edit-- adding code

In your view did load (or where ever appropriate),

```
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyBoardWillShow:) name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
```

In the method keyBoardWillShow:

```
-(void)keyBoardWillShow:(NSNotification *)noti {
     UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((1024-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (768-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/9, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
    else {
        viewLogin.frame = CGRectMake((768-viewLogin.frame.size.width)/2, (1024-viewLogin.frame.size.height)/2, viewLogin.frame.size.width, viewLogin.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have edited the answer with code. You should probably reset the position of the text fields back when keyboard hides.